# Xml parser doesn't work on other hostings

Tags: php, xml

My local page was parsing xml with no problems, but when I uploaded my code to other host, It doesn't work.. Does anyone know any issues?

Comment: There could be a whole host of problems LUL

Comment: What is your code for parsing the XML? You might be using something that requires a specific extension that isnt installed on your host

Comment: What parser? You provide no code. Same as "my car does not work"...

Answer (score 1):

Does your host have the same modules enabled?

On Ubuntu, you need to install the extension that might not enabled for you by default.
You may need to install these by doing `sudo apt-get install php-xml` followed by a web server restart.